# LinkedIn Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I would like to know, does anyone here have experienced dealing wth LinkedIn Javascript API's.

I'm a beginner in Javascript API's.Recently I've got a task where I have to create an application which can search the LinkedIn database based on the chosen skills.

For an example,user would want to find people who have a specific skill sets(for example java),they can input the skill set(by text or selection)and the application searches and returns all the people who match the skills set.

I've been reading through the documentation many many times and going through the forums but there dont seem to have complete reference to this.

Some of the answer's i've read is, it seems we can't search skills of the connection as skills are part of the full profile whereas search can only be done for basic profile's.

I've would like to ask,is this application possible to be developed? Is there any example for this application?

Do share your experience,

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: See http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inapipeoplesearch and http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields, looks to be simple.

Comment: yeah i've gone though that. But it doesn't explain,how to search using skills.

By the way thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

@Captain Jack,
If you are having some trouble, the first thing that I would request you to check is if your linkedin account through which you are creating your application/ Javascript API, has sufficient priviledges with Linkedin. There are certain levels of authorization that you may require if you would like to acquire more data from linked in.

The skills field is one such out of many that requires this authorization. Quote from linkedin website:
"***Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers
The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn program:***

from - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields"

So do you have this approval from Linkedin. If not then I dont think you're gonna be able to get this done.

Hope I have given you some info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the example for java, php and python on this [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide), it's available on this [one](https://github.com/linkedin/api-get-started) too.

Try this add `skill:(Java)` into your api url

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:
(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,skill:(Java)),
num-results)?
first-name=parameter&last-name=parameter
```

Comment: I've read those documentation.But it doesn't explain on doing search based on skills. 

thanks for your reply

Comment: What you want @captain jack

Comment: My task is to create an application that will search for people in linkedIn based on the skills. 

For example, if the user enter's java as input, the search will return all the people who have java as their skills.

Comment: Once again thanks for your response. I would like to ask,this is a REST API right, so do I have to create my own REST application to be able to test this API? Before this i've been using Javascript API to test few codes. How to use REST API? 

Sorry if I may sound noob. As i said, I'm very new to this.

Thanks once again